# converting little endian to decimal?

Tags: assembly

Could someone explain how to get an integer from a four-byte sequence in a little endian ?

I understand how we got 1468828554 (32-bit signed integer) from 0x8A 0x8B 0x8C 0x57 as we simply converted 578C8B8A into an integer, but how do we get the following?

> 0x8B 0x6A 0x73 0x86  = -2039256437 ( 32-bit signed integer)
>   0xAB 0x3A 0x7C 0x96 = -1770243413 (32-bit signed integer)
>   0x22 0x88 0x8A 0x56 = 1451919394 (32-bit unsigned integer)

Comment: For signed number representation, read about [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement). TL;DR: if the most significant bit is `1` the number is negative and you should subtract `2^32` from the converted value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various approaches to converting the value. Here is one, which will be shown to be equivalent to subtracting 2^32 (which is the position one greater than the greatest, 31, thus giving the 2s complement or inverted bits. You also need to add 1 if you flip each bit since you are doing the equivalent of in base ten turning 10,000 into 9999 to flip each bit.)

### STEPS

1. Each byte is in reverse order to its positional value, so flip the bytes: 86 73 6A 8B
2. Check if the MSB (most significant bit) is 1 or 0, here since 8 is greater than or equal to 1000 (binary) it is set, so it is negative. Thus, you must flip each bit, which can be done by subtracting each hex position from 15: 79 8(12) 95 74
3. Now convert to decimal by multiplying each power of 16 by the place value: 7*16^7 + 9*16^6 + 8*16^5 + 12*16^4 + 9*16^3 + 5*16^2 + 7*16 + 4 + 1
4. You now have -2,039,256,437 in base 10
5. This is the same as (8*16^7 + 6*16^6 + 7*16^5 + 3*16^4 + 6*16^3 + 10*16^2 + 8*16 + 11) - 2^32